# Uploading Document to Salesforce using REST API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

We want to be able to upload a document to DSA library using REST API. Looks like there is a SOAP API to achieve the same https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm 
Can we achieve the same using a REST API?

Comment: I don't know what a DSA library is, but RESTful apis are available https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

Comment: DSA == [Digital Sales Aid](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000057ZOHEA2)? "Built to synchronize with Salesforce Content"